# My 'cout' isn't giving correct value - why?

Tags: c++, sum-of-digits

Simple "sum of digits" code.  It compiles but when executed, the last cout gives a "0" for the num int rather than the actual user-input number.

Feel free to copy and paste this into your own compiler, if you're so inclined, to see what I mean.

How can I get this to output the correct "num" value?

~~~

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int num;
  int sum = 0;

  cout << "Please type any non-negative integer: ";
  cin >> num;

  while ( num > 0 ) {
    sum += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
  }

  cout << "The sum of the digits of " << num << " is " << sum << "\n";

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I removed the system("PAUSE"); and it seemed to work fine.  http://codepad.org/bwpGuJF8 (mind you codepad does not allow you to enter an input). The error I was getting before was this: Disallowed system call: SYS_fork

Comment: system("PAUSE") is a windows specific thing, on most (some?) unix machines it will try to feed that to the default shell.

A better way to get the desired behavir is to call cin:

cout << "Enter any key\n";
int wait;
cin >> wait;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've been modifying `num` all along until it becomes 0 (that's what your `while ( num > 0 )` statement *ensures*!), so OF COURSE it's 0 at the end!  If you want to emit what it was before, add e.g. `int orig=num;` before the loop, and emit `orig` at the end.

Comment: Correction: the while ensures `!(num > 0)`, not `num = 0`.  You could end up with -100 if the user enters -100.

Comment: Right -- if the user enters a negative number, it's going to stay untouched and similarly `sum` is going to remain zero. Not a particularly nice outcome, but then "it's impossible to build a foolproof system: fools are TOO ingenious!" -- defending against actively foolish user input is really an art more than a science;-).

Comment: Thank you Alex!  Before I posted this question last night, I had been trying "num = orig" (the reverse of what you suggested) and I kept getting 84 as my orig value when I had it emit "orig" at the end.  (BTW, why do you suppose *that* always the output I was getting in that case?  No matter the input, it always gave "84" as the output.)

In any event, your order works fabulously - thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `num /= 10` changes `num`.  If you want to get this to work, you should create a `temp` variable that you use to do all the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

For the next time, you can try to use a debugger. You'll find those "bugs" very easy!